# Merge another class value with form element in view file in zend framework 2?

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-form

In zf2 form I have created a element like

```
  $receivePerson = new Element\Select('receivePerson');
  $receivePerson->setLabel('To')
                ->setAttribute('class', 'required');
```

No I need to add another class attr value like error from view file.If I add error class value 
in form then my all code snippet like this.

```
$receivePerson = new Element\Select('receivePerson');
$receivePerson->setLabel('To')
              ->setAttribute('class', 'required error');
```

I use this code but it does not show any  expected result.

```
$element->setAttributes(array('class', 'error'));
```

After that I change my code and write like this

```
$element->setAttribute('class', 'error');
```

but it shows only error and my required class value has gone. what is the appropriate solution I don't find yet.

Answer (score 0):

Are you making sure you call prepare after you make your changes to the element and before the form is rendered?

```
$form->prepare();
```

You don't have to use the Element object to change this, there's a simpler way to do what you want using plain ond html to write out your forms:

myview.phtml

```
<li>
    <?php $class = XXXX ? 'one' : 'two'  ?>
    <?php echo $form->get('receivePerson')->getLabel() ?>
    <input class="<?php echo $class ?>" type="text" 
           name="<?php echo $form->get('receivePerson')->getName() ?>"
           value="<?php echo $form->get('receivePerson')->getValue() ?>"
    />
</li>
```

Comment: I could do my expected result like this way $element->setAttribute('class', 'error'.$element->getAttribute('class'));. Here you show a new technique that is also nice.